# how to show unicode characters in crystal report 9.0

Tags: unicode, crystal-reports

Please help me how to display Unicode characters(Chinese charactter) in the Report viewer .

I have one columns display but if i run that  query in DB itsexist chinee character in the table for that columns.

But I am display in  report design its coming like this(????????????TES/??/060/CN) SQuare boxes instead of chinse character.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

I am showing only 1 columns with Nvarchar , but how i need to enabled unicode character in crystal report (both english and chinese)
Below Screenshot displaying  data is coming like this instead Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Crystal XI R2 or later. Only those versions provide full support for UNICODE.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but now UAT is going on I can't switch now .Let me know any solution on this 9.0 version to support unicode characters.

Comment: afaik, there is no other option.